# Can one class log to different files depending on context?

Tags: slf4j, log4j2

I have a structure as follows:
Class A is started via main method
Class A starts Class B using ProcessBuilder (via main method of course)
Class B starts Class C using its Constructor

I want each class to have its own log and to use a single log4j2.xml file.

Appender has the following:

```
<RollingFile
    name="file"
    fileName="${sys:loggingFileName}.log"
    …
</RollingFile>
```

Each Class has code similar to this:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger (A.class);

System.setProperty ("loggingFileName", “A”);
LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext (false);
```

If there were only these classes involved, everything would work, but there are many other classes that do logging.

For example, Class D is referenced by Classes A, B, and C and only has this code:

```
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger (D.class);
```

I would like the output from Class D referenced from Class A to be in log A, but it may wind up in log A, B, or C.

Is there a way to construct the logs so that output for Class D winds up in:
log A when referenced from A
log B when referenced from B
log C when referenced from C

Comment: Have you asked this on the log4j-user mailing list?

Comment: Yes, it probably can be done but you would have to pass some kind of parameter so that D knows who is referencing it. E.g. `D d = new D(A.class);` or when you call a method like `d.foo(..., A.class);` so that the logic in D can get the logger for A by calling something like `LogManager.getLogger(A.class)`